# Ambiguity regarding Android documentation (How Android draws views.)

Tags: android

I was going through the Android documentation about how the views are drawn in an Activity.
But I have slight confusion regarding some information provided, please refer it below :

> Because the tree is traversed in-order, this means that parents will be drawn before (i.e., behind)  their children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear in the tree.

As per the above lines, it means in-order traversal is done, which means the left child should be drawn first before the parent, but this is contradictory to the above statement. 
Hence, I would appreciate if someone can clear things up on what really happens (w.r.t the order in which views are drawn).Thanks.

Comment: Well, it actually says that **the parents are drawn before. Then the children, in order** `parents will be drawn before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear`. What is unclear?

Comment: Yeah I guess that parent drawn before makes it pre-order instead of in-order. The starting of the statement, clearly states that **Because the tree is traversed in-order**, which makes one believe it is Left Child, the parent and then the right child. Sorry, but I do not fully understand whether you're saying it's pre-order or in-order traversal.

Comment: **In order**. Parent = 0, Children = 1, 2, ...

Comment: I guess for **In order traversal in a tree**, parent is drawn after the left child which makes, left child = 0, parent = 1, and right child = 2. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: **Wrong**. Parent = 0, left child = 1, right child = 2. The parent is **always behind** its own children.

Comment: I guess I'll wait for someone else to answer, because I am not getting what you intend to say. Maybe I'm missing something, but it still is confusing to me.

Comment: Let's make an **analogy**, maybe it makes more sense for you. You want to put some fruit (say an apple and a banana, in this order) in a canister. You **first** need **the canister** (which is the parent, the **container**). ONLY THEN, you can put the apple and the banana inside it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64928/discussion-between-gaurav-jain-and-funkystein).